# Python3 ODE Solver: MATLAB to Python interp1d

Tags: python, matlab, interpolation

I have a MATLAB code that looks like:

```
options = odeset('RelTol', 1e-3, 'AbsTol',[1e-3 1e-3]);
[Tx,X]  = ode45(@(t,x) stateEq(t,x,u1,Tu), [t0 tf], initx, options);
```

where in `stateEq` I define:

```
function dx = stateEq(t,x,u1,Tu)

    global E d G k b

    dx = zeros(2,1);
    u1 = interp1(Tu,u1,t);    % Interploate the control at time t
```

and I'm trying to get it to work in python3 by doing:

```
Tx, X = integrate.ode(stateEq(t,x,u1,Tu,G)).set_integrator('dopri5').set_initial_value(t0Range, initx, 'rtol', 'atol')
```

where:

```
def stateEq(t,x,u1,Tu,G):

    import numpy as np
    import scipy as sp
    from scipy import interpolate

    #global E d G k b
    dx = []
    x  = np.array(x)

    #print(x)
    u1 = np.interp(Tu,u1,t)
```

Here is the issue:

In MATLAB it takes this variable `t` from using the command `@(t,x)` in `ode45`, but how does this get defined in python? Because right now `interp1d` is failing because there is no defined `t` parameter.

Comment: I'm bumping this because I haven't gotten a response yet.